# Grabbing MetaData and outputting to XML

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the script to read the first line of files.txt, grab the data metadata requested and then output the .xml, move onto the next line and repeat.

I expect each line to have its own individual file with the meta data and then the next line to do the same.

Currently it creates all the individual files, but the data is combined and duplicated across them.

- The files.txt contains the full path and files that is being
  collected with the metadata  e.g.
  D:\data\testscript.ps1
  D:\data\workingfile.doc
  C:\Windows\temp\output.txt
- Filesv2.txt contain the filename of the xml output and is consistent
  in array with files.txt e.g
  D_data_testscript.ps1
  D_data_workingfile.doc
  C_Windows_temp_output.txt

```
$logdir = "C:\Users\gnome\Documents"

$inputPath = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\gnome\Documents\files.txt"
$inputSave = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\gnome\Documents\filesv2.txt"


#Get-*
$hash = Get-FileHash -Path $inputPath 
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $inputPath | Select-Object *
$metadata = Get-ChildItem -Path $inputPath | Select-Object *

#Loop each directory in $inputPath
#ForEach ($path in $inputPath){

      $output = ForEach ($path in $inputPath){ 

    Write-host Checking $path

          ForEach($inputSave in $inputSave){

              @{
                           
                #$log  = "$logdir\$inputSave.xml"
                 
                sha256Hash = $hash
                acl = $acl
                metadata =$metadata
     
        }
           $output | Export-Clixml "$logdir\test1_$inputSave.xml" 
              
     }
             
}
'''
```

Comment: What do files `files.txt` and `filesv2.txt` contain? You are readng these in as string arrays, but what is in them? Full path and filenames of other files you need to get the filehash and acl from? Also, you are iterating the array in variable `$inputSave by using the iterating variable the same as the collection you need to loop through in `ForEach($inputSave in $inputSave)`

Comment: files.txt contain the full path and filesnames that I'm collecting from e.g D:\data\testscript.ps1  and filesv2.txt contains the naming convention for the output so D:\data\testscript.ps1 turns into test1_ D_data_testscript.ps1.xml

Comment: Please ad this info with some examples to your question by clicking the [edit] link underneath. Also explain how the two arrays from the dfferent files match (just by array index?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, `files.txt` stores full path and filenames and `filesv2.txt` has new names for these files according to some naming convention to be used for the output xml filename.

Having both arrays separate from eachother in separate files is somewhat accident-prone, because all that links the file name to the convention name is the index in both arrays..

Below first creates a Hashtable from these arrays **assuming the indices match and both arrays have the same number of elements**

```
$logdir = "C:\Users\gnome\Documents"

$inputPath = @(Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\gnome\Documents\files.txt")   # full path and filenames 
$inputSave = @(Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\gnome\Documents\filesv2.txt") # naming convention for the output

# create a Hashtable where the input from files.txt is key and the naming convention for the output xml is value
$filesHash = @{}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $inputPath.Count; $i++) {
    $filesHash[$inputPath[$i]] = $inputSave[$i]
}

# now iterate
$filesHash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    Write-host Checking $_.Key 
    $output = [PsCustomObject]@{
        sha256Hash = Get-FileHash -Path $_.Key -Algorithm SHA256
        acl        = Get-Acl -Path $_.Key
        metadata   = Get-Item -Path $_.Key
    }
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $logdir -ChildPath ('{0}.xml' -f $_.Value)
    $output | Export-Clixml -Path $outFile
}
```